# what's the 0 in "0, 0, 0, 0 in b for b in bytes(4)"

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning the bytes vs text

```
In [179]: [b for b in bytes("text", "utf-8")]
Out[179]: [116, 101, 120, 116]
```

I could understand this because the number match each letter in ascii code,

```
In [185]: [ord(char) for char in "text"]
Out[185]: [116, 101, 120, 116]
```

When it come to number,

```
In [188]: [b for b in bytes(4)]
Out[188]: [0, 0, 0, 0]
In [189]: bytes(1)
Out[189]: b'\x00'
```

Why are there only 0 in bytes(4), what's the `x` in `b'\x00'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bytes()` does the same things as `ByteArray()`, except that the elements of its return value are immutable.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) for `ByteArray()`:

> If [the first parameter] is an integer, the array will have that size and will be initialized with null bytes.

So when you call `Byte(x)` where `x` in an integer, you will always just get a sequence of zero bytes of size `x`.

`\xhh` is python's [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for a byte with hex value hh when used inside a bytes literal. `b'\x00'` has a b in front of it, which means its a bytes literal.

Comment: Please add info for "\x"

Comment: @NitinPawar info added